# AKS How to access pods on node with public IP

Tags: azure-aks

We have a nodepool created with `--enable-node-public-ip` option (Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#assign-a-public-ip-per-node-for-your-node-pools)). Essentially each node within this nodepool has a public IP.

I can see there are pods running on these nodes. Can we expose these pods through these public IPs?

How can we access the Pods running on these nodes? It is even possible?